# Live stream peer to peer

Tags: android, live-streaming

I want to stream camera video of one android device to another device. This is what i am thinking, let say we have two devices Device-A, Device-B. Device-B stream its camera-video to a file stored in Device-A and Device-A play that video. See picture for more explanation.

[image]

So my Question is, is this practically possible ? How we manage that file in which we are streaming data this file will be updated continuously and will be played at the same time. So how we going to achieve that that.