# connecting two mobile phones over different network and then real time video streaming

Tags: java, android, video, video-streaming

I'm developing an application in which i want to connect two android phones over different networks and then want to stream user's video to one another with their own video e-g a user can see their own video and also the video of the friend who is connected with him over network.I want to do this thing without a server..Is it possible ??

Comment: You may refer to the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443372/live-stream-peer-to-peer

Comment: I guess you can, if you somehow come to know IP of both devices, then all will be remaining is opening a socket and pumping data through it. But know both devices IP will be an challenge, without having access to NAT.

Comment: Removed real-time tag, grammar fixes

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible see nanohttpd and you will have to connect both device using your app in same network and stream to a port listen to port